# Set a Value Threshold in R

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have the following data frame:

| Parameter | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0NO2 | 46 |
| 00O3 | 56 |

with a lot more parameters

```
c("00C6H6", "00CO", "00HR", "LAEQ", "00NO2", "00O3", "00PA", 
 "PM10", "PM25", "00SO2", "TEMP", "00VTH", "00UV")
```

However, there are certain parameters for which the values exceed the designated limit. Therefore, I would like to establish a maximum value for those parameters that have a specified upper limit, and replace any values surpassing this limit with the designated maximum value.

I already tried the following:

```
max_values <- c(
  "00C6H6" = Inf, "00CO" = Inf, "00HR" = Inf, "LAEQ" = 80, "00NO2" = 500, "00O3" = 300,
  "00PA" = Inf, "PM10" = 200, "PM25" = 100, "00SO2" = 600, "TEMP" = 50, "00VTH" = Inf, "00UV" = 15
)

Data21_Cleaned <- Data21_Cleaned %>%
  mutate(value = pmin(value, max_values[parameter]))
```

And tried another ways, but I can't make it limit the maximum values for the different parameters and replace them with the actual maximum value. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the thresholds in a separate tibble using `enframe`

```
mv_tib <- enframe(max_values, name = "Parameter", value = "max_value")
```

Then, you can join this tibble, and use `pmin` afterwards:

```
Data21_Cleaned %>%
  left_join(mv_tib, by = "Parameter") %>%
  mutate(value = pmin(value, max_value))
```